# Can't git push with error " master (pre-receive hook declined)"

Tags: git, openshift, push

I've Tomcat 7 as a cartridge and followed the steps given here - https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1088-how-to-deploy-pre-compiled-java-applications-war-and-ear-files-onto-your-openshift-gear

However, the last step of pushing the changes fails, repeatedly.

```
Vivek N@ACCOUNTINVALID ~/root (master)
$ git push --verbose
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the current behavior after the default changes, use:

git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

git config --global push.default simple

When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.

In Git 2.0, Git will default to the more conservative 'simple'
behavior, which only pushes the current branch to the corresponding
remote branch that 'git pull' uses to update the current branch.

See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
(the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)

Pushing to ssh://53c810bf5973ca46e70000a1@mailbostonisa-bisa.rhcloud.com/~/git/m
ailbostonisa.git/
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 20.69 MiB | 11.30 MiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: OPENSHIFT_DEPLOYMENT_TYPE is 'binary' - git-based deployments are disabl
ed.
To ssh://53c810bf5973ca46e70000a1@mailbostonisa-bisa.rhcloud.com/~/git/mailbosto
nisa.git/
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://53c810bf5973ca46e70000a1@mailbostonisa
-bisa.rhcloud.com/~/git/mailbostonisa.git/'
```

Please help with suggestions

Comment: That could be an issue on Openshift side (https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/can-not-git-push-git-pre-receive-hook-declined-problem), but there is no issue reported at the moment though (https://openshift.redhat.com/app/status)

Answer (score 1):

The git pre-receive hook is a script that runs on the server side every time it receives a push.  This error means that their server rejected your commit.  Unfortunately, the error you received is not very informative.  If you have access to the server, look in `./.git/hooks/pre-receive` and verify that it doesn't have any checks that your code fails.  You can checkout http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks for more on git hooks.